# min.js.map files not found, console logs. Getting unexpected CSS behaviour

Tags: javascript, ruby

I'm getting the following logs in my console

```
[2020-01-30 16:34:40] ERROR `/vue.min.js.map' not found.
[2020-01-30 16:34:40] ERROR `/raven.min.js.map' not found.
[2020-01-30 16:34:40] ERROR `/popper.min.js.map' not found.
```

I do not how to interpret this logs, definitely haven't found those files in my file system.
Should I have them? What are they for? How to fix this issue?

I suspect that this error has something to do with some weird CSS behavior when building the project and working locally.

Comment: can you post the full path of those files? and the line of codes where it is being called?

Comment: That's actually the whole path that the console throws me, there's I'm literally copying and pasting

Comment: I'm guessing that the problem comes from the fact that 
1. I'm using Jekyll for this website which is kind of abstract to me.
2. The website is using Bootstrap and jQuery, and I guess that those logs are coming from this fact, but that's me just being suspicious.